# Feedback Loop Filtering query using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following scenario (based on an actual scenario that cannot be shown here). Two inputs

1. A number `x`
2. A series of positive integers given as `IEnumerable<int>`

Now I want to find all groups of three consecutive integers in the series that can divide `x` with no remainder, and one group cannot overlap the other.

For instance: My series is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and user inputs `x=24`

Then my LINQ will give 1, 2, 3, but will not give 2, 3, 4 because those two groups will overlap in the series.

Now I *could* run a LINQ query that would basically run a "window" of 3 on the series and give me the several groups, and run a `Where` clause to find the group that will have all 3 numbers successfully dividing `x`. But every time I find a match, I need some kind of a *negative feedback* to tell my filter to omit the subsequent groups that will be overlapping to the matching one.

To understand it better, in the above example. I can generate several groups like

```
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5,
and so on
```

then I could say

```
myWindowsOf3Numbers
      .Where(w => x % w.Number1 == 0 && x % w.Number2 == 0 && x % w.Number3 == 0)
```

So I end up with code like this

```
var series = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var x = 24;

var windows = series.Select((number, index) => index + 2 < series.Count()? new { Number1 = series[index], Number2 = series[index+1], Number3 = series[index+2]  } :  null )
    .Where(groups => groups != null);

var matching = windows.Where(w => x % w.Number1 == 0 && x % w.Number2 == 0 && x % w.Number3 == 0);
```

The above will give me 1, 2, 3 and 2, 3, 4 both, but I want only the first one of the two overlapping.

Is there any LINQ-trick to do that or I have to use `foreach` (Like the following code)?

```
private class Match
{
    public int N1 { get; set; }
    public int N2 { get; set; }
    public int N3 { get; set; }
}

var series = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var x = 24;

var windows = series.Select((number, index) => index + 2 < series.Count() ? new { Number1 = series[index], Number2 = series[index + 1], Number3 = series[index + 2] } : null)
    .Where(groups => groups != null);

var matches = new List<Match>();

for (var i = 0; i < (series.Count() - 2); i ++)
{
    if (x % series[i] == 0 && x % series[i + 1] == 0 && x % series[i + 2] == 0)
    {
        matches.Add(new Match() { N1 = series[i], N2 = series[i + 1], N3 = series[i + 2] });
        i += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is  your *non-linq* code that you want to convert to linq?

Comment: @Eser I have not written any code yet, I am trying to approach it using LINQ.

Comment: And you think there is some magic in linq that you can't so with classical loops?

Comment: @Eser NO I don't think that. I know how to do it using classical loops, I am trying to approach the problem using 'functional approach' rather than iterative way. You totally misunderstood my question.

Comment: @Eser are you being intentionally dense? He's saying he can defer to a foreach but wants to know how to do it in LINQ if possible. Nothing wrong with wanting to learn.

Comment: @ap What am saying OP just wants a solution without showing any effort how to aproach to the problem.... And not in any way, a linq way :) SO is not "write a code for me" site

Comment: It's probably too much trouble to try to do all this in LINQ, and it wouldn't be very readable either.

Comment: @Eser My efforts are written in English. Too bad if you only understood C#. I have detailed how I am planning to approach it and where I am stuck.

Comment: @fahadash We don't need words... try to write some code and show it...

Comment: @Eser he's shown that he has existing linq queries that don't do quite what he wants. That's work shown imho and plenty to merit asking the question.

Comment: @ap `existing linq queries` ? a single *where* :))))

Comment: @JB06 I suppose there is no "Feedback Loop Filtering" in LINQ... I assume something could be done in F#, but may be C# is not there yet.

Comment: @Eser If you don't like the question. I think you should use your time elsewhere. And don't say 'we', you speak for yourself.... I have explained in plain English rather than writing the code for code-monkeys; If you don't understand the Logic explained to you in English and you prefer to see the code, I cannot help you. I recommend you use your time for something better.

Comment: @fahadash I guess all you can say is "monkeys". A bad approach for one in need and can't do anything by himself other then speaking....

Comment: @fahadash `I have explained in plain English rather than writing the code`, explaining your problem is good but not enough. SO is not a code writing service. You should try to write some code and ask the real problem with your code..... If you need documents/algorithms/advise, your are on the wrong site...

Comment: @EZI Ok so SO is definitely not a site for 'Write code for me' but I assume what you are implying is it is a place for 'Here is my code, please adjust it to best practice code'-ONLY place.... And questions concerning, "Here is a  problem, what is the best way to approach it" are not welcome here... I got it... Would you rather share how you would approach the problem without writing any single line of code? Or that goes against the guidelines?

Comment: @fahadash: Your question has an interesting problem at its crux, but putting it to the community without showing that you invested efforts in solving it, will invite close votes. Please edit your question and include the efforts you made so that it isn't closed and you can be helped (and everyone can enjoy solving a good problem).

Comment: @fahadash No,  `'Here is my code, please adjust it to best practice code'` is for stackExchange's codereview site.....

Comment: @displayName I edited the question. It's too hard to reason with the zealots. You were so nice to edit my question and ask me politely, I had to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the challenge, here is one possible "pure" LINQ solution, but frankly I'd never use something like this:

```
int x = 60;
var series = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.AsEnumerable();
var matches = series
    // Create the sliding window
    .Select((e, i) => new { index = i, group = series.Skip(i).Take(3).ToArray() })
    // Remove the non matching
    .Where(e => e.group.Length == 3 && e.group.All(v => (x % v) == 0))
    // Remove the overlapping 
    .Aggregate(new { next = 0, result = Enumerable.Empty<int[]>() }, (prev, next) => 
        next.index >= prev.next ?
        new { next = next.index + 3, result = prev.result.Concat(new[] { next.group }) } :
        prev).result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you said LINQ ...:

```
        var series = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        var x = 24;

        var matchingWindows = series
            .Select((number, index) => index + 2 < series.Length ? 
            new { Number1 = series[index], Number2 = series[index + 1], Number3 = series[index + 2], Index = index } : 
            null)
            .Where(groups => groups != null)
            .Where(w => x % w.Number1 == 0 && x % w.Number2 == 0 && x % w.Number3 == 0)
            .ToList();

        int lastTakenIndex = -1;

        var nonOverlapping = matchingWindows.Where(w =>
        {
            if (lastTakenIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (w.Index <= lastTakenIndex + 2) return false;

                lastTakenIndex = w.Index;
                return true;
            }

            lastTakenIndex = w.Index;

            return true;
        }).ToList();
```

It uses a lastTakenIndex (= the start index of the 3-group that was last taken that matched the condition) which is modified as a side-effect during the Where filtering.